# use core data object model without using persistence

Tags: core-data

the App I'm working on does not store objects in persistence store for reasons... but it has a complex object graph that is created from JSON received from webservices.

In order to have a sane view of this object graph that is created, I was thinking of being able to use core data's object model GUI, but without the core data API's or framework.

Is it possible to do so? As all the fetch apis are in the NSManagedObjectContext and nothing in the NSManagedObjectModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible. When you call `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL: options:error:` you tell it what kind of persistent store you want to use in the first argument. One of the possibilities is `NSInMemoryStoreType`, which is just what it suggests-- something that's only in memory and not written to a file. It exists as long as your app keeps running, then it disappears. (Usually people use `NSSQLiteStoreType` but that's not required).

Keep in mind this means that all of your model objects will be in memory. If you have a lot of them (or if they're big) that could be a problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. I read up on that now and it sorts out what I needed to achieve :-)